# Triggering cloud function from alert policy in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert

I created a Google Cloud function that executes a database query and returns a count:

```
import psycopg2

def my_function(request):
  """Runs a custom SQL query on a Cloud SQL database and returns the result."""

  # Connect to the Cloud SQL database.
  conn = psycopg2.connect(host='<YOUR_DATABASE_HOST>', database='<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>', user='<YOUR_DATABASE_USER>', password='<YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD>')

  # Create a cursor.
  cur = conn.cursor()

  # Run the custom SQL query.
  cur.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> WHERE <YOUR_FIELD> IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(<YOUR_FIELD>)) = ''')

  # Fetch the result of the query.
  result = cur.fetchone()[0]

  # Close the cursor and connection.
  cur.close()
  conn.close()

  # Return the result of the query.
  return result
```

The testing was successful, it returns the correct value. I am now trying to create an alerting policy that triggers this function every hour and checks if the number returned increased or remained the same, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I tried using this MQL code but it did not work: `sum(resource.labels.function_name = "<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>")`

Comment: Do you want Cloud Monitoring invoke your function to get the value? And then alert if hour over hour the values are not the same, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Monitoring only based its analysis on the logs. So, it can't invoke a function to get values.

Therefore, the correct alternative is the following

- Update your Cloud Function to write the result in the logs (and return "hello world" instead of results)
- Create a Cloud Scheduler that invoke your function every hour
- Create a [log based metric in Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) based on the logs that you write with your Cloud Functions
- Create an [alert policy on the metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#create-policy)

Comment: Oh, I understand. Great, Thank you! Do you happen to know how I can change the above function to write the count to logs?

Comment: Print(...). Google Cloud listen to standard output. Write in it it, it will appear in the logs